# Firefox does not remembers data entered into text box which was generatd by my firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

My Firefox extension dynamically adds a username/password fields into every page. The problem is it does not remember what I enter as it normally do. Why this is happening?

Comment: When is this element being added (before, during or after `load` event)? Does it have an `id` attribute?

Comment: After load event and it does not have id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [nsLoginManager.js](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/nsLoginManager.js), forms are normally filled when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires (see `_fillDocument()` call). From what I understand, you insert your elements after that event is already processed so that their values are no longer restored. You could call [nsILoginManager.fillForm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NsiLoginManager#fillForm%28%29) explicitly however to restore field values after you changed the form:

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/login-manager;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsILoginManager)
          .fillForm(form);
```

This should be sufficient, from the code it seems that having an `id` attribute isn't necessary.